# Spectral classification for crops

Tags: remote-sensing, classification, erdas-imagine

I'd like to do a classification using  a multispectral raster (1 Blue 475, 2 Green 560, 3 Red 668, 4 Red Edge 717, 5 Near IR 840). I'd like to classify the crops (kiwi plants).
[image]

I tried a few unsupervised classification with ERDAS like NDVI, DVI, SARVI, TBDVI RDVI. I used RDVI to to do a 90 class classification, then blackened the classes that didn't show the crops.
[image]

Is there any better way to get the crops classified?